# How can Django be installed on a Windows computer without administrator privileges?

Tags: python, django

I want to install Django on my university provided Windows 7 computer. We have Python 2.7 already installed, but not Django.  I tried several ways to install Django without the need for administrator privileges but couldn't succeed in doing so.  How can I install Python packages on Windows without administrator privileges?

Comment: If you can create a virtualenv elsewhere, and you can use it in your uni windows 7 pc(copy-paste virtualenv) and install django.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up Django on an instance of [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com/), throw it on a flash drive, and then use it on your university PC. You might need to configure portable python on a different machine, but I don't think so.

Here's a reference to getting started with Django on Portable Python: [Portable Python - Django](http://portablepython.com/doc/2.7/django/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I manage to install it on my usb but still unable to run it because of system restriction I got this following message while i try to execute it

"Windows cannot access the specified device path or file. You may not have appropriate permissions."

Comment: When you say 'execute it', do you mean you get the error upon launching portable python, or when trying to install django?